# How should I handle css in react app, when there is custom css retrieved in runtime?

Tags: css, reactjs, dynamic

I am working on ReactJS app (with Webpack) for webshop. This app retrieves some shop config from backend (as JSON object). This config contains customCss property that should override css of my webshop app. I am using css modules, but i think it is not easy to override css this way, so my question is what would be the bast way to handle css in my app, and override css with this property in the runtime?

Answer (score 0):

> React: css is Js

this the great idea you can go throw it for more guidance

https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js